# open link in a pop up window in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, window

I am trying to open a link in a pop up window. I wrote the following code. But when I click the link it does not open a pop up window. And also it opens a different link than the specified link

link:

```
<a href='#' class= 'tooltip' title='click to see information' onclick='linkopen(event);'><?php echo $info->individual; ?></a>
```

script:

```
function linkopen(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open(<?php echo base_url().'marketing/incoming_call/info/'.$info->party_id; ?>, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function linkopen(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("<?php echo site_url('marketing/incoming_call/info').'/'.$info->party_id; ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}
```

You missed double quote when call `open()`

Comment: Can you show your source code what is generated after PHP. view source

Answer (score 0):

Have experience b4. Solved by this way.

```
<a href='#' class= 'tooltip' title='click to see information'onclick='linkopen();'><?php echo $info->individual; ?></a>


<script>
function linkopen() {
    window.open("<?php echo site_url("marketing/incoming_call/info/$info->party_id"); ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=100, width=795, height=500px");
}
```